# Difficulty with jQuery Image Slider

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble creating a jQuery image slider that can also contain other elements (ie: `<div>`, `<a>`, `<span>`) I've skimmed the internet for tutorials and downloaded several projects only to find that they are not easily editable. I've concluded that the best way will be to make one from scratch. Does anyone know of a good  documentation source that can help walk me through the basics of creating basic jQuery image slider that is able to show all of the elements in my html?

Below is the html/js:
Html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="pbody">
    <div id="slides">
        <div title="Slider 1" style="background-image: url(images/TCM_slider1_WW_v1.jpg); display:block;" class="current billboard">
            <p class="big">Slider 1</p>
            <a href="#" class="black_button">
                <span>Learn more</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div title="Slider 2" style="background-image: url(images/TCM_slider2_WW_v1.jpg); display:block;" class="billboard">
            <p class="big">Slider 2</p>
            <a href="#" class="black_button">
                <span>Learn more</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="controls">
        <li class="current">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ol>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var cycle = window.setInterval(next, 4000);
function prev() {
$('#slides .billboard .current')
    .removeClass('billboard current')
    .prev().add('#slides :last')
    .first().addClass('billboard current')
;
$('#controls .current')
    .removeClass('current')
    .prev().add('#controls :last')
    .first().addClass('current')
;
}

function next() {
$('#slides .billboard .current')
    .removeClass('billboard current')
    .next().add('#slides :first')
    .last().addClass('billboard current')
;
$('#controls .current')
    .removeClass('current')
    .next().add('#controls :first')
    .last().addClass('current')
;
}

$('#prev').on('click', prev);
$('#next').on('click', next);
$('#controls li').on('click', function() {
$self = $(this)
    .addClass('current')
    .siblings('.current').removeClass('current')
    .end()
;
$('#slides  .billboard .current')
    .removeClass('billboard current')
    .siblings(':nth-child(' + ($self.index() + 1) + ')').addClass('billboard current');
});
```

Comment: Try this... http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 1):

I've created a barebones proof-of-concept HTML slideshow that should help get you started.

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVSDL/15/).

- The slideshow contains prev/next buttons and page number navigation.
- It can have any number of slides and will loop infinitely.
- The slides can contain anything including HTMLElements.
- There are no transitions but they can be added with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) or [CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions)

Comment: Hello Anstosa, In response to your recommendation, i updated my question. I attempted to use the code you provided on your jsFiddle account. I posted the html and js right into my question instead of linking to a file. I think my syntax may be incorrect in the area of using multiple classes in the js. im not sure what the best workaround would be. Any suggestions? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Here is the [working jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/gc9pr/10/) of your code. Your syntax was right. You don't need to add and remove the `billboard` class though. Just leave it alone and it won't be removed. What is that class for? You can style the slide containers with `#slides > div`

Comment: Thank you for the help. The class is used for positioning the button and `<p>` inside the actual slide. I updated my classes to read `#slides > div` etc but i must be missing something in my stylesheets that is disrupting the script. Can incorrect styles in my CSS affect the way the script operates?

Comment: Yes, check the JavaScript Console for errors and can you post your CSS as well so I can take a look.

Comment: I went onto JSFIDDLE and made an account and uploaded my html/css/js there. The link to see it is: http://jsfiddle.net/williamwong/aRQ4a/1/

Comment: [Fixed.](http://jsfiddle.net/aRQ4a/3/) All I changed was to select jQuery 1.7.1 from the sidebar. Make sure that you are importing jQuery before this script runs and that you are using 1.7+

Comment: wow. thank you! everything is working great. I appreciate your help. what is the way to give you points/recognition on here?